# PageView pages are not disposed, app runs out of memory and crashes

Tags: flutter

I have a photo gallery in my app that uses a `PageView` to display one high resolution image per page.

When swiping quickly through the gallery, I can reliably crash my app. In my case on iPhone 12 Pro the 27th image kills it at 2.8 GB memory:

```
* thread #12, name = 'io.flutter.1.io', stop reason = EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=2867 MB, unused=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00000001de32c64c libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove + 76
libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove:
->  0x1de32c64c <+76>: stnp   q0, q1, [x3]
    0x1de32c650 <+80>: add    x3, x3, #0x20             ; =0x20
    0x1de32c654 <+84>: ldnp   q0, q1, [x1]
    0x1de32c658 <+88>: add    x1, x1, #0x20             ; =0x20
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

Looks cryptic, but clearly says that **all available memory is used up**.

Some of the images have an overlay like a switch or a form field as part of the page. I recognized that their state is maintained while I scroll back and forth. Since I'm using the `PageView.builder` constructor, I was actually expecting the pages to be disposed and only a fixed window of pages around the current page would stay in memory when swiping. When I navigate away from the gallery after scrolling 20 images (so the whole PageView gets disposed) and back to the gallery, I can swipe another 20 images and I can repeat this without crash. So it seems that disposal of the `PageView` clears the memory.

How can I force the pages to be disposed?

Google gives me a lot of Q&A on how to keep the pages in `PageView` alive and that confirms my expectation that the PageView should dispose the resources unless I tell it explicitly something different.

Summary:

1. I use `PageView.builder`
2. Page state seems to be maintained for all pages by default
3. App crashes after x pages have been rendered

Here is my PageView code for reference:

```rb
PageView.builder(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => GalleryCustomChild(image: viewModel.images[index]),
  itemCount: viewModel.images.length,
  controller: viewModel.pageController,
)

class GalleryCustomChild extends StatelessWidget {
  final ImageData image;

  const GalleryCustomChild({required this.image, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PhotoView(
      minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
      maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered,
      initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
      backgroundDecoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
      imageProvider: FileImage(
        File(image.filePath),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I guess you are not disposing of your pageviewController. Please try disposing of the controller by overriding the dispose() method.

Comment: Thank you guys for the input :) I tried both, but unfortunately to no avail. The cached image size is printed as 0 or some reasonable amount, but the crash will still happen.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm facing the exact same issue. I'm displaying images in a PageView widget. I can scroll through around 30 full size (1 to 2MB) images on my iPhone 11 pro before the app suddenly crashes. On the memory page in Dart Dev Tools I can see the memory usage keeps increasing when flipping through pages. For me though, when I dispose the PageView widget after say 25 swipes without crashing, and continue with the next image, it crashes after about 5 swipes. It seems to me the images are being cached and cleared when the amount of space taken up becomes too large.

Comment: We were using `photo_view` package. See this still open issue, it has a possible fix: https://github.com/bluefireteam/photo_view/issues/478